# Fetch value of a input type and store in variable

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I have following input type

```
<input id="crp-project-title" class="crp-project-title" type="text" placeholder="Enter project title" value="EXTERIOR" name="project.title">
```

Its value is `value="EXTERIOR"`. I want to fetch the value and store in a variable. I am not getting any idea regarding this. I am trying to modify plugin (career portfolio) according to my project and its part of that.

Comment: when you want to get the value? is there any submit button? or you want to get value on page load?

Comment: @urfusion Its an image light box plugin. In the above input tag the name of the image use to store in the `value="EXTERIOR"`(EXTERIOR is image name). I want to store that value in variable so that i can use this variable to show image name as caption on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your html form:

```
<form method="POST" action="process.php">
    <input type="text" name="foo">
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Your Php form processing page (process.php):

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        $foo = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'foo', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is front end code, if you are trying to move front end data to server side it must pass through the server. i.e. $_POST...

now you can either do this with AJAX / PHP or PHP / HTML only

```
<?php
 if(isset($_POST[project.title])
    $var = $_POST[project.title]; //its now in a varible
?>
<form method="POST" action="thispage.php">
<input id="crp-project-title" class="crp-project-title" type="text" placeholder="Enter project title" value="EXTERIOR" name="project.title">
<input type=submit value="PRESS ME TO SUBMIT VALUE TO VAR">
</form>
```